# Update temp table number n+1 from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have what I feel should be a very simple update task, but I'm stuck at the moment with the following problem. I have a temporary table for which I would like to update all rows to a value of n+1 from another table; for example:

Person:

```
+--------+----+
| Name   | N  |
+--------+----+
| A      | 1  |
| A      | 5  |
| A      | 2  |
| B      | 8  |
+--------+----+
```

@temp_Person:

```
+--------+--------+
| Name   | NPlus1 |
+--------+--------+
| A      | NULL   |
| B      | NULL   |
+--------+--------+
```

I need to update @temp_PersonTable so that the values in the NPlus1 column are derived from the N column in the Person table, something like:

```
UPDATE @temp_table 
SET NPlus1 = ((SELECT MAX(N) FROM Person WHERE Person="A") + 1)
WHERE @temp_table.Person = Person.Name

UPDATE @temp_table 
SET NPlus1 = ((SELECT MAX(N) FROM Person WHERE Person="B") + 1)
WHERE @temp_table.Person = Person.Name
```

So the result would be:

```
+--------+--------+
| Name   | NPlus1 |
+--------+--------+
| A      |     6  |
| B      |     9  |
+--------+--------+
```

Do I need to write an individual UPDATE statement for each case? I am wondering how I would write a SQL script to iterate through each DISTINCT Name in Person and make the update, and currently thinking this task would be easier to do from a separate application to update the table using a foreach loop.

Comment: Just create a CTE with Name and N+1, grouped by Name, and use that to update your table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to get the values as part of a subquery first and then `JOIN` to that.

```
UPDATE tp
SET
    NPlus1 = SQ.max_N + 1
FROM
    @temp_Person TP
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(N) AS max_N FROM Person GROUP BY Name) SQ ON
    SQ.Name = TP.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single statement

```
update #temp_Person
set NPlus1 = (select MAX(N) + 1 from Person where Name = #temp_Person.Name)
```